# Spree Error SQLite3::ConstraintException: PRIMARY KEY must be unique

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

i'm currently working on a spree project.When i try to run `rake db:seed`  it shows me following error.

```
rake aborted
SQLite3::ConstraintException: PRIMARY KEY must be unique: INSERT INTO "spree_countries"       ("name", "iso3", "iso", "iso_name", "id", "numcode") VALUES ('Chad', 'TCD', 'TD', 'CHAD', 39, 148)

Tasks: TOP => db:load_dir
```

any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the seeds have already been loaded. The first time was when you ran `rails g spree:install` or `spree install`.

Is there a reason why you want to load them twice?